# Cursor from login screen does not go away after logging in

Tags: gnome, login, cursor, 20.04

I had to take a picture with my phone because the "double" cursors do not show up in screenshots.

[image: I had to take a picture with my phone because the "double" cursors do not show up in screenshots]

I have this problem with the GNOME session and the default Ubuntu session on both Wayland and Xorg, and I tried switching the DM to lightdm, also without fixing the problem. I wonder what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem after activate fractional scaling in display settings. Try to disable this.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include more detail. How do you disable fractional scaling? (perhaps include a photo or two)